# ghc-mod can't find a user installed module

Tags: haskell, ghc-mod

I have a situation where `ghc-mod` can't find a module installed in my ~/.ghc/ directory.

The program (foo.hs) is just:

```
import Control.Monad.Loops
main = undefined
```

`ghci` loads `foo.hs` without any errors.

`ghc-pkg list` produces the output:

```
/Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/7.8.3-x86_64/usr/lib/ghc-7.8.3/package.conf.d
    Cabal-1.18.1.4
    GLURaw-1.4.0.1
    ...
~/.ghc/x86_64-darwin-7.8.3/package.conf.d:
    ...
    monad-loops-0.4.2.1
```

but `ghc-mod check foo.hs` errors out with:

```
x.hs:4:8:Could not find module ‘Control.Monad.Loops’Perhaps you meant  Control.Monad.Cont (from mtl-2.1.3.1)  Control.Monad.List (from mtl-2.1.3.1)  Control.Monad.Trans (from mtl-2.1.3.1)Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

`ghc-mod` is located in ~/Library/Haskell/bin and `ghc-mod -v` emits:

```
ghc-mod version 5.0.1.2 compiled by GHC 7.8.3
...
```

What's kinda odd is that I don't get an error when loading `foo.hs` in Emacs under haskell-mode, and presumable that also uses `ghc-mod`.

Is there a way to debug this further and/or configure ghc-mod to look in my ~/.ghc directory?

Comment: Is this part of a cabal project? If so there's a bug in the current ghc-mod which may require a "cabal clean" if you've changed the installed packages at all.

Comment: No - I don't have a cabal file in the directory.

Comment: Cabal is usually the easiest and safest way to go when installing user libraries.  If you add a cabal file, point it at your `foo.hs`, and run `cabal install`, you should be good to go.  You'll need to add `monad-loops` as a dependency in the cabal file as well, but `cabal init`, which will create a skeleton file for you can sometimes figure this out for you from your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that `ghc-mod` will look for a `cabal.sandbox.config` file in all parent directories of the current working directory and use that if it finds one, and that was hiding my `~/.ghc` package directory.

Comment: Looks like I found your old question; and while I have a similar problem, this isn't the solution that would solve my problem. I did a search and I don't have any `cabal.sandbox.conf` hiding in parent directories.  That leaves me with still no solution, unfortunately... :-(